# if $\lim{x_n} = - \infty$ then $\lim \frac{1}{x_n} = 0$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits

Prove $\lim\frac{1}{x_n} = 0$,  if $\lim x_n=-\infty$

Attempt

From $\lim x_n=-\infty$
$$\forall a < 0 \exists N : \forall n >  N \implies x_{n} < a $$

Picking an $\epsilon > 0$ and letting a = $\frac{1}{-\epsilon}$

From the given
$$\exists M = M_{\frac{1}{-\epsilon}} : \forall n > M = M_{\frac{1}{a}} \implies {x_n} < a = \frac{1}{-\epsilon} < 0 \implies a_{n} < a = \frac{1}{-\epsilon} < 0 \implies -\epsilon = \frac{1}{a} < \frac{1}{x_n} < 0$$

hence
$$\forall \epsilon > 0 \exists N = M_{\frac{1}{-\epsilon }} : \forall n > N = M_{\frac{1}{-\epsilon}} \implies -\epsilon < \frac{1}{x_{n}} < 0 < \epsilon$$

And since this is the definition of the limit of a sequence $\lim\frac{1}{x_{n}}$ = 0

Comment: so what's your question?  This is good.  (Except for the weird part where you introduce $a_n$.  But I assume that was a typo.)